# How long can a fireplace go without cleaning/inspection if it's never used?

Tags: maintenance, fireplace, inspection

I have a gas fireplace that I have never used, nor planned to use.  Then we lost power on the coldest day I've ever seen here (gas furnace - check, electric blower - oops) and I'm kicking myself for not getting it swept and inspected.  So if I get it swept out but never start a fire, what would the maintenance interval be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically you'll never have to get it cleaned or inspected again as you're not putting smoke, soot and damp air up it.

However, if you do get it back in working order you'd be better off to keep using it on a regular basis and then cleaned regularly too.

Comment: Thanks.  I just can't imagine a fire when it's 40F (avg winter low for my area)

Comment: @Steve - I don't think you have to use it every day ;)

Answer (score 2):

A gas fireplace really doesn't need to be "swept" - gas won't deposit creosote in the chimney and gas flue temperatures are limited, so "chimney fire in a gas fireplace" is not a thing that happens. The similarity to a wood-burning fireplace is quite small.

An annual inspection of the flue venting and check on the fuel/air mixture should be entirely adequate. Many people go considerably longer without having their gas water heaters or furnaces checked, but annually is a good safe option *and may be enshrined in insurance coverage, for one thing.*